# how to convert timestamp to date in jasper report ireport designer 4.5.0

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I need to convert or format my `timestamp` to date in the report I am generating using Jasper Reports iReport designer 4.5.0

I am get the stardate as **2012-04-01 12:00 AM** and I want to convert or format it to dd/mm/YYYY.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: forum member

I am able to view the date in format dd/mm/YYYY by changing Pattern format. But when this report is generated with java I am not able to get the report startDate of format dd/mm/YYYY.

So is there any way after the .jrxml compiles successfully to my server side the report generated should also have startDate of format dd/mm/YYYY

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the `iReport` designer, you can set the pattern of fields or variables. Select the field and you shall see the *properties* panel on the right side. Then find the **Pattern** property and set it according to your need.